# How are some python built-in functions coherent with pythons method resolution?

Tags: python, built-in

For example the following signature of the max function in the documentation:

```
max(iterable, *[, key, default])
max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
```

I thought python resolves names in the same namespace to one distinct item at a time, with no method overloading.

So how is this realised?
Even if it uses overloading and distinguishes at a "builtin-level" during the call which method is resolved, depending on what actual parameters are passed, how is this coherent with the rest of python?

Or am I misinterpreting it, and both signatures are actually represented using the same signature and are just written out as two variants for us humans to understand?

Comment: I would presume it is the same function only internaly it distinguishes based on type of arguments. For example if first argument implements iterable then first form is used

Comment: It is similar as you would do for example in javascript based on type of argument. There is no overloading

Comment: You've misread the signatures. It should be `max(iterable, [key=func])` or `max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func])`. `max` decides what to do based on the number of positional arguments it receives; the *keyword* argument `key` is the same in either case.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, sure it can check if first two arguments are iterable or numbers. Still I think there is no overloading. Only internal case macthing based on type of arguments passed. The signature would be `max(*args)`

Comment: @chepner I don't get exactly what you mean. I copied it from the official https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max.

Comment: Sorry, I ran `help(max)` in a Python 2 interpreter, not a Python 3 interpreter. But, the docs you copied from explain that the behavior of `max` depends on the value it receives as its first positional argument. If it's an iterable, it's the *only* positional argument allowed. Otherwise, an arbitrary number of positional arguments are allowed. It's not overloading, because the test is performed *inside* the only method there is, rather than the *compiler* deciding which function actually gets called.

Comment: @chepner Yes, that the error handling and distinction is done in the function itself sounds reasonable. If it's an iterable, it doesn't necessarily have to be the only positional argument though, since some iterables can be comparable as well.

Comment: @user10385242 True; it would be more accurate to say that `max` iterates (or tries to) over a single positional argument, but treats multiple positional arguments as individual values.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much right.

The seconds variant is just an unrolled list - which is an iterable. So the iterable version is the more general of the two.

Comment: Well, but arg1 and arg2 aren't directly part of the iterable tuple args,
after a little bit of testing, I suppose the signature is (\*args,\*\*kwargs) and it chooses the iterable variant if len(args)==1 else the other variant.
It also throws a custom keyword argument error message like other built-in functions do, so perhaps this is the *real* signature.

Comment: That's the generic signature for literally *all* python functions.

Comment: Sure, but they are all annotated as real signature unknown. Is this the real interpreted signature of the actual functions as well? The built-ins throw a different error message than for defined functions you know the signature to, so they may really be *args,**kwargs and then raising errors in the function for undefined parameters